Unable to update to 22.04.1 LTS due to broken packages
I am unable to update to Kubuntu 22.04 and am getting daily messages that support will end soon. /var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log shows:
2024-09-02 22:52:43,977 DEBUG none of the '['ubuntu-desktop', 'kubuntu-desktop', 'xubuntu-core', 'xubuntu-desktop', 'ubuntustudio-desktop', 'lubuntu-desktop', 'ubuntu-gnome-desktop', 'ubuntu-mate-core', 'ubuntu-mate-desktop', 'ubuntukylin-desktop', 'ubuntu-budgie-desktop']' meta-pkgs installed
2024-09-02 22:52:43,977 DEBUG guessing 'kubuntu-desktop' as missing meta-pkg
2024-09-02 22:52:44,467 ERROR failed to mark 'kubuntu-desktop' for install (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)
2024-09-02 22:52:44,736 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: fontconfig-config'
2024-09-02 22:52:44,740 DEBUG abort called

I have tried a purge and reinstall of fontconfig-config, but this has not fixed the issue.

Did you try sudo apt install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop

That did not fix it. The output of sudo do-release-upgrade is An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. with no further details.

Well, my suggestion is to boot up with the USB use TRY Kubuntu backup everything you want and install new Kubuntu. But wait a bit with installing and see if anybody else has a suggestion.
